# Solution of second order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I consider a second order linear ODE :

$$
x^{2\beta+2}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial x^2}+(a+x^{2\beta})x\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}+(b+x^{2\beta})V=0.
$$

I am expecting that the above equation can be reduced to Whittaker's equation. However, I couldn't. How can I solve the above equation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did this equation come from? have you already performed a change in variables such as $t = x^{\beta}$ or some other transformation to get to this point? as I would hate to cover old ground.

Comment: In the tags you have pde when I think you want ode.

Comment: My first instinct tells me to use Taylor series expanded about some point.  Since there is no obvious point about which to expand one would assume 0 but then you have to check whether it's a regular singular point blah blah blah.  Does this sound like a good track for you?

Comment: Well. $t=x^{\beta}$ or some other transformation does not work well. Simply speaking, I want to find some appropriate transformation to reduce the above equation to well known ODE such as Kummer's and Whittaker;s equation. But I can't see the way.

Comment: Additionally, a change of variable $t=x^{-2\beta}$ gives the following equation : $$ t \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}+(C_1-t)\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{C_2}{t}u=0$$. It is similar to the Kummer's equation. But $\frac{C_2}{t}u$ term is in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=x^{-2\beta}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}=-2\beta x^{-2\beta-1}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}$

$\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial x^2}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(-2\beta x^{-2\beta-1}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}\right)=-2\beta x^{-2\beta-1}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}\right)-2\beta(-2\beta-1)x^{-2\beta-2}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}=-2\beta x^{-2\beta-1}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}\right)\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}+2\beta(2\beta+1)x^{-2\beta-2}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}=-2\beta x^{-2\beta-1}\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial t^2}(-2\beta x^{-2\beta-1})+2\beta(2\beta+1)x^{-2\beta-2}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}=4\beta^2x^{-4\beta-2}\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial t^2}+2\beta(2\beta+1)x^{-2\beta-2}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}$

$\therefore x^{2\beta+2}\left(4\beta^2x^{-4\beta-2}\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial t^2}+2\beta(2\beta+1)x^{-2\beta-2}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}\right)+(a+x^{2\beta})x\left(-2\beta x^{-2\beta-1}\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}\right)+(b+x^{2\beta})V=0$

$4\beta^2x^{-2\beta}\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial t^2}+2\beta(2\beta+1)\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}-2\beta(ax^{-2\beta}+1)\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}+(b+x^{2\beta})V=0$

$4\beta^2x^{-2\beta}\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial t^2}+(4\beta^2-2a\beta x^{-2\beta})\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}+(b+x^{2\beta})V=0$

$4\beta^2t\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial t^2}+(4\beta^2-2a\beta t)\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}+\left(b+\dfrac{1}{t}\right)V=0$

$4\beta^2t^2\dfrac{\partial^2V}{\partial t^2}-t(2a\beta t-4\beta^2)\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial t}+(bt+1)V=0$

With reference to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=px%5E2y%22-x%28qx-p%29y%27%2B%28rx%2B1%29y%3D0